# How can I get amount of users created in the last 24 hours in an event sourcing system?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I am learning about event sourcing and projections, and something that I thought should be simple apparently it is not.

## **Context**

I have an application using event sourcing.
Users are created and when such thing happens events such as "UserWasCreated" are stored in an event stream.

## **Problem**

I want to display a "total amount of users that joined in the last 24 hours" panel.

I am not sure how to approach this with projections. The way I understood projections is that it will read the event stream when it is created for the first time, then it will listen to events to do some work.

However if I want to have a projection that counts users created in the last 24 hours, it is not enough listening to "UserWasCreated", because I also have to stop counting users from the past.

### **How can I approach this?**

Comment: Maybe you can create a sliding window projection that will keep track of "UserWasCreated" events in the last 24 hours. When a new "UserWasCreated" event occurs, we add it to the projection and remove any events older than 24 hours. The projection will maintain the count of events in the window and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get amount of users created in the last 24 hours in an event sourcing system?

The usual answer: set up a process that reads the events being written into the event story and copies the information you need into another data store that is more suitable for querying.

For example, if you know how to get "users created in the last 24 hours" from a relational database, then you create a process that reads events from the event store and copies the information you need into the relational database.